# Problem on defining tuple notation that includes a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm struggling with preparing a notation for a project im working on that includes the following:

I have a tuple $s_i$ that is currently described by a timestamp and a value like this $(t_i, v_i)$

Now i would like to say that tuple $s_i$ also has a set of attributes $\{x\}$ of size $L$ that do not change in time...

How would i add this to the tuple $s_i$? does $(t_i, v_i, \{x\})$ with $|x|=L$ make sense or do i have to add more details of set $x$ in the tuple?

Comment: Do you mean that the set $A$ of attributes is the same for all pairs $s_i=(t_i,v_i)$?

Comment: yes Christian, lets say the set is A then $s_i$ will always include them e.g. $A$ may include some metadata of $s_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array $(s_i)_{1\leq i\leq N}$ of pairs $s_i=(t_i,v_i)$, whereby all entries $s_i$ of the array share a set $A$ of properties. If this fact is clearly spelled out at the moment this array is introduced it is not necessary to carry the $A$ along in the notation.

If, however, the entries $s_i$, in addition to $t_i$, $v_i$, carry additional data $A_i$ (individual sets of properties), to which is made individual reference in the sequel, you have to include $A_i$ in the notation, so that you then obtain an array of triples $s_i=(t_i,v_i,A_i)$ $(1\leq i\leq N)$.

Comment: ok so its this simple...